# Unexpected Behaviour of bit field operator in C

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    struct bitfield
    {
        unsigned a:5;
        unsigned c:5;
        unsigned b:6;
    }bit;
    char *p;
    struct bitfield *ptr,bit1={1,3,3};
    p=&bit1;
    p++;
    printf("%d",*p);
}



Explanation:
```

- Binary value of a=1 is 00001 (in 5 bit)
- Binary value of b=3 is 00011 (in 5 bit)
- Binary value of c=3 is 000011 (in 6 bit)

  My question is: In memory how it will represented as?

When I compile it's giving output 12 I am not able to figure out why It's happening: In my view let say memory representation will be in below format:

```
00001 000011 00011
        |        |
       501       500 (Let Say starting address)
```

Please Correct me If I am wrong here.

Comment: What is `ptr` used for?

Comment: Why didn't you print *p without incrementing it? You may as well print both bytes and remove all doubt.

Comment: The struct will be padded to to boundaries of an `int`. Padding is target architecture dependent, and so is endianess.

Comment: @APerson: The C standard does not specify that a struct containing bit-fields will be padded to an `int`. The storage unit used for bit-fields is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual representation is like:

```
000011 00011 00001
     b     c     a
```

When aligned as bytes:

```
00001100 01100001
       |        |
       p+1      p
```

On the address (p+1) is `0001100` which gives 12.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not completely specify how bit-fields are packed into bytes. The details depend on each C implementation.

From C 2011 6.7.2.1:

> 11 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

From the C11 standard (6.7.2.1):

> The order of allocation of bit-ﬁelds within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-deﬁned. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspeciﬁed.

I know for a fact that GCC and other compilers on unix-like systems order bit fields in the host byte order which can be evidenced from the definition of an IP header from an operating system source I had handy:

```
struct ip {
#if _BYTE_ORDER == _LITTLE_ENDIAN
        u_int     ip_hl:4,              /* header length */
                  ip_v:4;               /* version */
#endif
#if _BYTE_ORDER == _BIG_ENDIAN
        u_int     ip_v:4,               /* version */
                  ip_hl:4;              /* header length */
#endif
```

Other compilers might do the same. Since you're most likely on a little endian machine, your bit field will be backwards from what you're expecting (in addition to the words being backwards already). Most likely it looks like this in memory (notice that the order of your fields in the struct in your question is "a, c, b", not "a, b, c", just to make this all more confusing):

```
01100001 00001100
|        |
byte 0   byte 1
|  |     |     |
x  a     b     c
```

So, all three bit fields can be stuffed in an int. Padding is added automatically and it's at the start of all the bitfields, it is put at byte 2 and 3. Then the `b` starts at the lowest bit of byte 1. After it `c` starts in byte 1 two, but we can only fit two bits of it, the two highest bits of `c` are 0, then `c` continues in byte 0 (`x` in my picture above), and then after that you have `a`.

Notice that the picture is with the lowest address of both the bytes and the bits on the left side growing to the right (this is pretty much standard in literature, your picture had the bits in one direction and bytes in another which makes everything more confusing, especially adding your weird ordering of the fields "a, c, b").

I none of the above made any sense run this program and then read up on byte-ordering:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        unsigned int i = 0x01020304;
        unsigned char *p;
        p = (unsigned char *)&i;
        printf("0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)p[0], (unsigned int)p[1], (unsigned int)p[2], (unsigned int)p[3]);
        return 0;
}
```

Then when you understand what little-endian does to the ordering of bytes in an int, map your bit-field on top of that, but with the fields backwards. Then it might start making sense (I've been doing this for years and it's still confusing as hell).

Another example to show how the bit fields are backwards twice, once because of the compiler deciding to put them backwards on a little-endian machine, and then once again because the byte order of ints:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct bf {
                unsigned a:4,b:4,c:4,d:4,e:4,f:4,g:4,h:4;
        } bf = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        unsigned int *i;
        unsigned char *p;
        p = (unsigned char *)&bf;
        i = (unsigned int *)&bf;
        printf("0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)p[0], (unsigned int)p[1], (unsigned int)p[2], (unsigned int)p[3]);
        printf("0x%x\n", *i);
        return 0;
}
```